# Switch case inside a container

Tags: flutter

I have a `rectangle` and I'm trying to change it's `colour` based on the `boolean true` or `false`. But `switch` statement seems like it's not in the correct place and it says `expected an identifier`. Where to place `Switch` logic?

```
Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: circleSize,
            height: circleSize,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Container(
               
               switch (OnOffVariable) {
                  case false:
                     color: Colors.grey,
                    break;
                  default: color: Colors.purple,

                  case true:
                     color: Colors.purple,
                    break;
                  default: color: Colors.purple,

                },
              )
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: You can unless you send your variable to a method that eventually will return from a Switch, but you can't do it directly, you must do Container(color: _myMethodWithSwitch(OnOffVariable)). Plus, if you're using a bool login, why are you trying to use a Switch? Use a Ternary Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `switch-case` if it only has two condition. Use ternary operator will do.

```
child: Container(color: OnOffVariable == false ?
                      Colors.grey : Colors.purple)
```

Comment: twice the  ``color`` parameter?

Comment: bool values don't need to check equality as the default value will be "true" if you compared on a ternary operator. with color: OnOffVariable ? Colors.grey : Colors.purple is already enough or to equal false you change OnOffVariable to !OnOffVariable